# How do you test Account Linking with Actions On Google with a separate test account prior to deployment?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

I've built an Action using API.AI, and set it up with integration to Actions On Google. A webhook is used for fulfillment, together with account linking. I've followed the directions [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/testing) to complete testing using my main google account that gives me access to the unpublished action in the web simulator and on my Google Home device that is set up with the same account.

Now it's time to deploy my Action. [These instructions](https://developers.google.com/actions/distribute/deploy#register_your_conversation_action) detail the process. One of the steps is to provide testing instructions for the Google reviewers that will approve the deployment. If you use account linking, it is necessary to provide them with test user credentials. Here is specifically what they request:

*Provide any additional information needed to test your agent. If your agent requires account linking or login information, you must provide a username and password for a test account. Please make sure that any provided accounts are not real user accounts. This information will only be used by the review team, and will not be visible to users.*

I've set up a test account for this purpose. I would obviously like to test my Action using the test account (instead of my main account) prior to submission for deployment. How do I do this?

If I use the  [web simulator](https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/web-simulator)  and login with the test account, when I try and invoke the Action with my invocation name I get 'Sorry, this action is not available in simulation'.

When developing an Alexa Skill, Amazon provides for this as described [here](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/articles/182/how-do-i-add-new-users-to-my-developers-account.html). While researching, I see references to similar provisions for Android developers with Google Play [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2528691?hl=en). Where is the same thing for Actions On Google?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The test account is for the account linking step only.

To test your action in the simulator, you should be using the developer account you used to submit the action for review. The test account is used once your action is invoked and account linking is required to continue using your action.

Comment: I follow you, but then what is the point of the nested logins in the simulator? After launching the simulator, you first have to login at the top right corner of the window. Then, after you hit the 'Start' button, you are prompted to login again. This would logically indicate that you login to the simulator at the top right with your developer account, and then login with the test account after hitting Start. Doing this would then allow you to associate the test account with the given access token, making it possible for other users to test prior to deploy instead of just the developer.

Comment: When you click on the web simulator start button, you should log in with your developer account you used for previewing or submitting the action. The test account is for the action reviewers to check if they can use your account linking.

Comment: Thanks Leon. I was hoping that Google provided a mechanism for testers (with different accounts than the developer) to access Actions/agents prior to deployment. That does not look to be the case with current capabilities. Hopefully in the days ahead Google will provide a framework like what Alexa dev teams can do now. Disappointed but accepting the answer as a limitation we have to work with. Thanks for your inputs.